# Apache httpd offline installation on Debian

Tags: apache-2.2, php, httpd

how can I install Apache HTTPD offline on a Debian Linux distribution?
On this case I have no internet access at all on this machine, so I was searching for binary distributions of Apache Httpd and could not find any.

I'll need to enable php5 support and also PostgreSQL support for PHP.
Does anyone here knows any binary distribution of these packages that I could actually use? I've tried Xampp, but it only works on 32 bit machines, so this is out of question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download a Debian CD/DVD. Then with the apt-cdrom command you can add it as an apt source. From there you can then install apache using apt, as if you were connected to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried searching here? http://packages.debian.org/stable/

In any case, you're going to have a difficult time without network access because of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://packages.debian.org/stable/httpd/apache2

Check the packages installed on your system - as you see on the page above, the `apache2` has some dependencies (red dots and "dep" infront of package names in related packages - for example [apache2-mpm-worker](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apache2-mpm-worker) and [apache2.2-common](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apache2.2-common) here). Each of those packages, has other dependencies, and they have more,...

You have to install the whole dependency tree for the package `apache2` to work. If you have an option to temporarly connect the machine to the internet, I'd use that option, since it saves alot of error-prone manual clicking and downloading of packages.